# Mockito for functional interface used in jdbc batch update

Tags: java, spring, springmockito

I have a method for `jdbcBatchUpdate`. I need to write a Mockito test case for it. Below is my code:

```java
jdbcTemplate.batchupdate("sql",list,100, (PreparedStatement ps, obj) ->
    { ps.setString(1, object.getstring()) }
```

I need to cover the statements which are inside of the prepared statement.

I tried mocking `ParameterizedPrepareStatementSetter`, but it did not work.